# Photoshop: Adding colored background to transparent canvas quickly

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background

Imagine a transparent canvas with different layers, like this:

[image: layers on transparent canvas]

I want to fill the whole background with a color, so the result would be like:

[image: objects with colored background]

The workflow I use for this is:

- add new layer
- select all
- fill with background-color
- moving the layer to the very bottom

Is there a way to accomplish this faster/easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want an actual "Background" layer (as Photoshop defines the locked "Background layer"), but rather just a solid color filled layer below all other layers....

- <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (new Layer)
- <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> **or** <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> (fill with foreground/background color)
- <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> (move layer to bottom of layer stack)

Can take as long as *1 second* once you get accustomed to the shortcuts.

This *could* all be recorded in an action for batch processing. But if you aren't batching images, an action won't really be any faster for a single image here or there. Although you may prefer 1 shortcut press for an action, as opposed to 3 shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks, using the shortcuts is a good improvement of my workflow (didn't know that one existed for »move layer to bottom of layer stack«). So this might be the best solution.

Comment: @BNetz the other bracket ( ] ) will move to top.. don't use Shift and you can move layers up or down within the stack - the shift key is what makes it "to bottom/top". It will also honor groups... move to bottom/top of group first, then hit the shortcut again to break out of a group and move to bottom/top on the second hit. And Option/Alt [ or ] will *highlight* layers up or down. These are *very* handy shortcuts when I'm working.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to maintain the layer structure then try this:

1. Choose a new background colour by clicking on the background colour square in the toolbar
2. Add a new layer using the shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept
3. Do *Layer > New > Background from Layer*

That's just 3 steps, one less than yours.

For more speed, you could record steps 2 and 3 above as an Action. And set up a Function key to run the Action.

[image]

Then when you want to use it, all you'd need to do is select a new background colour, and hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Function key to run the Action. That's just two steps!!!

For the ultimate speed, if you want to apply this to a whole bunch of images in one folder, you could run the Action using *File > Automate > Batch* - choose the Action you recorded, set the source folder and a destination folder, and OK to run it.